# Whats the difference between firebase web app and firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

what is the difference between the firebase web app and firebase hosting?
As far as i can tell the web app is used for an app thats actually just a browser,
and the firebase hosting is used just for websites.

Comment: See a related question on why would you need to link the two: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64409754/3082178

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Firebase **for** Web-Apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) is a JavaScript library and [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) is a web-hosting platform.

The JS can be loaded from just any web-server, but on Firebase Hosting it is better integrated with other the components in the Firebase ecosystem - and it can be deployed with the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

Comment: Correct! You can use Firebase Hosting to host any static assets, like a web site or just some images, no matter if they use other Firebase services or not. You can also use other Firebase services (like Authentication, Firestore, or FCM) in your web app, no matter where that app is hosted. But if you use both Firebase Hosting and other Firebase services, you get some extra benefits, like [implicit initialization of the Firebase services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) without having to copy/paste a configuration snippet.