# What benefit does linking Firebase web app to Firebase Hosting site brings?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-console

What for should I link the web app to the Firebase Hosting site in the console? What are the benefits and effects?

[image: console]

The difference between the two is covered here: [Whats the difference between firebase web app and firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59996743/3082178).

The linking is mentioned in the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#register-app, but the rationale and consequences are not explained.

Comment: There are no specific benefits of doing this. Firebase hosting is just that - a hosting service. If you have an existing site with them, you can link it to your web-app using the `link to a firebase hosting site` button. If you don't link it, you will get the default `firebaseapp.com` or `web.app` URLs assigned to your web app.

Comment: Actually you can add custom domain to a Firebase hosting even if it's not linked to a web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase [support documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9325939?hl=en) says:

> You may need to link your web app to your Hosting site in the Project settings if you chose not to set up Hosting when you registered your web app with your Firebase project.

> If you're using Firebase Hosting for your web app, you can use the [reserved Hosting URLs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) to add Firebase SDKs and manage your Firebase configuration for your app.

In short, if you're using those special Hosting URLs that begin with `__`, in particular, `/__/firebase/init.json`, it helps to have linked your app to Hosting so that the configuration is complete.  By my recollection, the config will then have a correct FCM config in this case.

Comment: Do you know if there's any benefit to linking a web app to your hosting site you're importing firebase from an npm package?

Comment: @Doug seems it's the only reason and it's the answer. Thank you for the support link. I feel it would benefit the developers to include the same information into the https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls article and into point #3 of https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#register-app to make the information accessible. @Johnny - it doesn't seem there is any benefit for projects importing firebase from `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure partial import of the Firebase JavaScript SDK and only load the Firebase products that you need. If you're using a bundler (like Browserify or webpack), you can import individual Firebase products when you need them.

> Note: You can use this option even if you use Firebase Hosting, but make sure to add your Firebase config object before initializing Firebase.

1. Install the Firebase JavaScript SDK:

a. If you don't already have a package.json file, create one by running the following command from the root of your JavaScript project:

```
npm init
```

b. Install the firebase npm package and save it to your package.json file by running:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

2. To include only specific Firebase products (like Authentication and Cloud Firestore), import Firebase modules:

   // Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be
   listed first
   import firebase from "firebase/app";
   // If you are using v7 or any earlier version of the JS SDK, you should
   import firebase using namespace import
   // import * as firebase from "firebase/app"

   // If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for
   Analytics
   import "firebase/analytics";

   // Add the Firebase products that you want to use
   import "firebase/auth";
   import "firebase/firestore";
3. Initialize Firebase in your app:

   // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project
   configuration
   // For Firebase JavaScript SDK v7.20.0 and later, `measurementId` is an
   optional field
   const firebaseConfig = {
   // ...
   };

   // Initialize Firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to the linking of the Firebase Hosting site to the Firebase Web app. Even more, everything described in this answer can be applied to any JS application that uses Firebase SDK, regardless of where it is hosted.